# Automatic login after activate account using ion auth

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, ion-auth

I am using ion-auth in my codeigniter. I would like to do a automatically login after account activated via email. Can i simply pass the hash password to the email tpl and hidden it and use it for `$this->ion_auth->login()` ?

Answer (score 2):

Inside the register() function, just call the login() function, and submit the unhashed normal password.

You have this, because it is a variable that you used to submit for the hashing - just reuse the original var

Comment: Actually i am required a user to activate their account with a link through email so i cannot just call the login() inside the register(). But i have no idea how to get the user email and password to automatically login the user after they clicked the link   activate their account.

Comment: Just copy the code from the login section, after the 'if password is correct' section. From memory you create a session there

Answer (score 0):

If your activating an Account you should be retrieving the user data anyway, simply setup the session data for that account manually and redirect inside activate()